# What happens to the stock price if most of the share holders stop trading that stock?

Tags: shares, stock-valuation

For most companies, on most days not even 1 percent of the total free float shares are traded every day.

Apple has 4.33bn shares in free float. **Hypothetically**, what would happen if nearly all the owners of the stock stopped trading in the hope that its price will rise in the future or in expectation of a dividend or some other incentive?

In this situation, let's say that only 100 shares are being traded every day by traders.  Do they have absolute control over the price (Not Value) of the stock? Can they drive the price of stock to insanely low/high levels?

Comment: You are aware that this is the state of pretty much EVERY company? MOST shares are not traded at all because MOST shares are there to back voting power for those sitting in the boards or long term investments that keep shares for YEARS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this situation lets say only 100 shares are being traded every day
>   by a bunch of traders do they have absolute control over the price
>   (Not Value) of the stock ? And can they drive the price of stock to
>   insanely low/high levels ?

And then once they drive the price up enough, other people will be willing to sell some of their shares. And the floodgates will open.

Note the current price is the value. That is the price of the last trade. Now some people think the price will move in a particular direction because the perceive it is under or over valued. That perception will be what makes some people decide to buy or sell.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say there are ten million shares, and 9,990,000 are in the hands of shareholders who are holding on to their shares and are not even looking at the stock market. 10,000 shares are traded.

What would happen is that the price can go massively up or down due to demand and supply, with no realistic relation to the value of the shares whatsoever. If the company is worth $50 million, someone could offer to buy some small number of shares for much more than $5, and the shareprice would shoot up. If someone tried to trade significant number of shares, the price would immediately go to what the shares are really worth.